# Creating a new backbone view in a yeoman scaffolded backbone project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, yeoman

`yeoman init backbone:view input`

This generates two files: app/scripts/templates/input.ejs and app/scripts/views/input-view.js

How do instantiate this view from within the application?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with latest [backbone genearator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) with yeoman 1.0beta.
We have made lot of improvements on it including [Precompiling ejs templates](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/20). You don't want to worry about templates, yeoman will precompile it you.

You can instantiate the InputView as you want and just use the template method to work with ejs. A sample code is provided below.

```
Todo.Views.InputView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/input.ejs'],

    render: function(){
       $(this.el).html(this.template());
    }

});
```